# Converting a drone orthophoto saved as KMZ to TIFF in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, convert, kmz, orthophoto

Dragging a drone-obtained orthomosaic image saved as a KMZ file (167mb) into QGIS results in the image being very poor resolution. But when KMZ file is loaded into Google Earth, it's very high resolution.
Is there a way to covert the KMZ into a TIFF inside QGIS so that I can view the high res image in QGIS?

Comment: Easiest way would be to ask the creator of the KMZ to provide you with data fitting QGIS, I guess.

Comment: Use something like 7-Zip to crack into the KMZ, copy out the raster file and add that to QGIS.  What does that image look like?

Answer (score -2):

Okay as I found there is not an easy route, I used "Mygeodata" convert tool which cost $9. I also reprocessed the original data in webodm.
I haven't tried using the 7-zip method mentioned.

Its a shame, as the kzm file in google earth is very easy to work with, and only 160mb. The geotiff produced is 700mb which makes qgis very slow to render.